# Update element in array in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I want to update the tasks' first object in the array for example. Remember that tasks array belongs  inside another array.

eg. {"firstName": "multiple lines",
"lastName": "multiple lines"}

I tried the following but couldn't make it work:

```
   const index = req.params.id;
     const { firstName, lastName, taskIndex } = req.body;
      
      const foundTask = await Task.findById(index); //to Find index from parent array
      const foundTaskItem = await foundTask.tasks[taskIndex]; // to find the object to update
    
// Need correct below
      Task.update(
        { _id: ObjectId(index), tasks: foundTaskItem },
        { $push: { }
      ); // I feel this is wrong

 [ 
        {
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "firstName": "multiple lines",
                    "lastName": "multiple lines"
                },
                {
                    "firstName": "multiple lines2",
                    "lastName": "multiple lines2"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5f22e48a97097d24e416bdf9",
            "additional": "testing",
            "date": "2020-07-30T15:17:30.236Z",
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "tasks": [
                {
                    "firstName": "Michael ",
                    "lastName": "Jordan"
                },
                {
                    "firstName": "Scottie",
                    "lastName": "Pippen"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5f248750e2e0b01180c49283",
            "additional": "Chicago Bulls",
            "date": "2020-07-31T21:04:16.519Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]

     [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChDcJ.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the tasks using update like this:

```
Task.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: ObjectId(index), tasks.firstName: "multiple lines2" },
      { $set: { "tasks.$.firstName": "updated multiple lines2" } },
      { new: true, sort: { _id: -1 } }).exec()
      .then(result => {})
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your code but it didn't work unless I put quotation marks in "tasks.firstName":  I want it to be dynamic. I did the following. I set the $set: to be dynamic so I used my req.body variable firstName but how do I make the tasks.firstName dynamic? It will only work if I hardcore exactly the existing value  Task.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: index, "tasks.firstName": makethisdynamic },
    { $set: { "tasks.$.firstName": firstName } },
    { new: true, sort: { _id: -1 } }
  )
    .exec()
    .then(result => {})
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });

Comment: The problem with my schema is that I don't have an id to each object in the tasks array so I can't tell Mongoose this is the item to look for. I rely on the index which I correctly can get using req.body.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a moron. I solved it by adding .firstName in the line `const foundTaskItem = await foundTask.tasks[taskIndex].firstName`; and using foundTaskItem as the value of "tasks.firstName":.

```
const index = req.params.id;
  const { firstName, lastName, taskIndex, additional } = req.body;
  console.log(taskIndex);

  const foundTask = await Task.findById(index);
  const foundTaskItem = await foundTask.tasks[taskIndex].firstName;
  
  Task.findOneAndUpdate(
    { _id: index, "tasks.firstName": foundTaskItem },
    { $set: { "tasks.$.firstName": firstName } },
    { new: true, sort: { _id: -1 } }
  )
```